# Color issue on dc.js bar chart when filtered into a narrow range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I'm working on a dc.js bar chart.The chart has three colors in it's color array, based on the barchart's value and whether they're above, below, or at average for the numerical range. It uses an outside filter that recreates the chart value based on the specifications passed in. If you use the outside filter to narrow the chart's y value to a relatively small range, the bar becomes a single colored chart (specifically the third color in the color range). Further examination seems to suggest it's not related to the dc.js filtering, but potentially what happens when the range of the values is narrow enough.

The color changes correctly when the range is wider, but when it gets to be a narrow range, suddenly the bars all become the same color.

The chart:

```
 that.ownerChart
            .width(400)
            .height(400)
            .margins({top: 0, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20})
            .dimension(that.dims.dOwner)
            .group(that._remove_empty_bins(that.groups.gOwner, (d) => { return d.value.avg; }))
            .ordering(function (x) {
                return x.value.avg * -1;
            })
            .on('filtered', onFilter)
            .fixedBarHeight(30)
            .cap(cap).othersGrouper(false)
            .elasticX(true)
            .renderTitleLabel(false)
            .leftLabel(function(x) {
                return x.key;
            })
            .leftLabelWidth(160)
            //The problematic line might be here
            .colorScale(d3.scale.quantize().range(that.colors));
```

Edited for clarity based on previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to help with a working example. That said, it's probably that `d3.scale.quantize()` is retaining the domain of values from the unfiltered chart.

I've seen similar problems with choropleths in dc.leaflet.js. It's actually a design choice whether you'd like the colors to always remain consistent, or to be scaled to the current domain for more contrast.

You can use [calculateColorDomain](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.colorMixin+calculateColorDomain) to recalculate the domain on each redraw:

```
chart.on('preRedraw', function(chart) {
    chart.calculateColorDomain();
});
```

This will call the color accessor for all values in the chart and replace the color scale's domain with the array of color values.

Comment: Hey Gordan, thanks for the answer. I tried implementing it but it seems my problem is slightly different than I first described. 

The code actually already recreates the chart on filter, so calculating the color domain doesn't seem to be the problem. The single color seems to appear regardless of whether or not this line is added as soon as the range is small enough.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it'll be hard for me to know what you're talking about without seeing a running example. But `d3.scale.quantize()` is sort of an advanced form of rounding, so may all the remaining values are close enough that they collapse to the same value?

Comment: That could definitely be it. Thank you. Sorry that I don't have a working version properly removed to give you.